# C# Intellisense in VS Code randomly stopped working today

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Keywords are still recognized but only new user-defined classes are recognized, using namespaces isn't recognized either, code runs fine but really annoying to code like this.

Tried everything for hours, even to the point of running a Windows 10 VM, with a new user doing a clean install of VS Code (with only the C# and .NET Install Tool for Extension Authors extensions) and .NET 7.0 SDK but still not working.

I was considering re-installing Windows on my main system but seeing as how it's not working on the VM either that would be pointless, anyone else having this problem too?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What changed about the C# extension for VS Code's IntelliSense in the v2.0.320 release?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76850403/what-changed-about-the-c-sharp-extension-for-vs-codes-intellisense-in-the-v2-0)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### TL;DR

The issues is caused by `v2.x.x` of the Visual Studio Code C# extension which does not have the same set of features (includes some unprecedented features, but also lacks some features) as the current `v1.x.x` (= *OmniSharp* or *O#*) versions. The goal in the future however is for `v2.x.x` to support what `v1.x.x` has already been supporting.

You have one of four options:

- Stay on >= `v2.0.320` and add a solution file (see section *Update 2023-08-05*) which includes your project
- Revert back to a OmniSharp powered version (versions <= `v1.x.x`) (see section *Original answer*)
- Go back to OmniSharp *by going to the Extension settings and setting `dotnet.server.useOmnisharp` to true. Next, uninstall or disable C# Dev Kit. Finally, restart VS Code for this to take effect.* (quoted from [Github - dotnet/vscode-csharp - How to use OmniSharp](https://github.com/dotnet/vscode-csharp#how-to-use-omnisharp))
- Wait for the feature parity to come in future `v2.x.x` versions (see linked Github issues in section *Update 2023-08-09*)

#### Update 2023-08-09

As pointed out in the comments below by [starball](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11107541/starball) and the thread [What changed about the C# extension for VS Code's IntelliSense in the v2.0.320 release?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76850403/what-changed-about-the-c-sharp-extension-for-vs-codes-intellisense-in-the-v2-0) on SO the general issue is that with versions >= `v2.0.320` Microsoft has decided to switch to the new Roslyn Language Server instead of using [OmniSharp](https://www.omnisharp.net/) (also often referred to as *O#*) which it has been using for versions prior to that (See [Github Releases - Changelog v2.0.320](https://github.com/dotnet/vscode-csharp/releases/tag/v2.0.320)). Microsoft did get some heat for that (see [Visual Studio Magazine](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2022/06/16/csharp-vs-code-tool.aspx)) as this will introduce closed-source functionality.

The new `v2`, as of now, lacks some features the OmniSharp versions provided. Looking at the list of known issues there are however plans to reach a feature parity between the two versions in the future.

Here the known issues as of *2023-08-09* based on [Github - dotnet/vscode-csharp - Known Issues in v2.0.320](https://github.com/dotnet/vscode-csharp/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#known-issues-in-20320):

> - Diagnostics related feature requests and improvements [#5951](https://github.com/dotnet/vscode-csharp/issues/5951)
> - [O# Parity] FixAll support for code fixes and refactorings [#5735](https://github.com/dotnet/vscode-csharp/issues/5735)
> - [O# Parity] Nuget restore [#5725](https://github.com/dotnet/vscode-csharp/issues/5725)
> - [O# Parity] Support loading projects/files without a solution file [#5722](https://github.com/dotnet/vscode-csharp/issues/5722)
> - [O# Parity] Some csproj projects will not correctly load [#5721](https://github.com/dotnet/vscode-csharp/issues/5721)
> - [O# Parity] Run and debug tests in context [#5719](https://github.com/dotnet/vscode-csharp/issues/5719)
> - Debug from .csproj and .sln [#5876](https://github.com/dotnet/vscode-csharp/issues/5876)

Note that issue [#5722 - [O# Parity] Support loading projects/files without a solution](https://github.com/dotnet/vscode-csharp/issues/5722) addresses the problem faced here.

With that being said, you have the possibilites as outlined in my previous answers:

- Stay on >= `v2.0.320` and add a solution file (see section *Update 2023-08-05*) which includes your project
- Revert back to a OmniSharp powered version (versions <= `v1.x.x`) (see section *Original answer*)
- Go back to OmniSharp *by going to the Extension settings and setting `dotnet.server.useOmnisharp` to true. Next, uninstall or disable C# Dev Kit. Finally, restart VS Code for this to take effect.* (quoted from [Github - dotnet/vscode-csharp - How to use OmniSharp](https://github.com/dotnet/vscode-csharp#how-to-use-omnisharp))
- Wait for the feature parity to come in future versions (see linked Github issues)

#### Update 2023-08-05

It seems the issue only occurs if you have a project which is not listed in a solution file, so you can create a solution file e.g. using `dotnet new sln --name <solution name>` and then add the project(s) to that solution using `dotnet sln add <project path>`.

It is working with the new version `v2.0.328` (released today 2023-08-05) for me when I have all my projects added to a solution file.

#### Original answer

I've faced the same issue today (2023-08-04). This is due to an update of the extension to `v2.0.320`. You can fix this by reverting back to version `v1.26.0`.

You can revert using the UI by going to `Extensions -> C# -> Install Another Version`:
[image: Revert C# Extension version]

There also is an open [Github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/vscode-csharp/issues/6024) related to this.

Comment: That worked, thank you very much, now I can get back to work.

Comment: then would this issue be covered by https://github.com/dotnet/vscode-csharp/issues/5722?

Comment: please has anyone resolved this error, I am currently having it, I have downgraded C# extensions to 1.26.0 removed, c# dev tool kit and reload/restarted severally. Even changed the C# extensions to 2.15.30 to use OmniSharp but no resolution. please help