# How to enable intellisense for C# in vscode on ubuntu when dotnet was installed with rtx

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I am not able to get intellisense for C# on vscode.

I used [rtx-cli](https://lib.rs/crates/rtx-cli), which is basically like [asdf](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf), to install `dotnet 7.0.306` on `Ubuntu 22.04.2`. I can run `dotnet` command on my terminal.

I enabled shims with `rtx` as well, so there is a `$HOME/.local/share/rtx/shims` in the path. `which dotnet` points to inside that directory.

In VSCode, I installed the [recommended Microsoft C# extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp). I also set the following 2 settings in my user level vscode config:

```json
"dotnetAcquisitionExtension.existingDotnetPath": [
    "$HOME/.local/share/rtx/installs/dotnet/7.0.306/dotnet",
],
"dotnet.dotnetPath": "$HOME/.local/share/rtx/installs/dotnet/7.0.306",
```

Here is the output of `dotnet --list-runtimes`:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.9 [$HOME/.local/share/rtx/installs/dotnet/7.0.306/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.9 [$HOME/.local/share/rtx/installs/dotnet/7.0.306/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

And here it is for `dotnet --list-sdks`:

```
7.0.306 [$HOME/.local/share/rtx/installs/dotnet/7.0.306/sdk]
```

I created the project with `dotnet new console --framework net7.0` which gave me a folder with `Program.cs`, `myapp.csproj`, an `obj` directory. I also created a `myapp.sln` file with `dotnet new sln`.

When I open VSCode, I get the notification that `.NET Core SDK cannot be located: A valid dotnet installation could not be found...`

I am not able to get any auto complete or error squiggles in vscode when I edit the `c#` file.

**NOTE:** `$HOME` everywhere up above is a placeholder. I actually used the real absolute path.

Comment: Might be cause by this issue/ behaviour of the C# extension for VS Code: [C# Intellisense in VS Code randomly stopped working today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76836174/c-sharp-intellisense-in-vs-code-randomly-stopped-working-today)

Comment: @Mushroomator I tried both of the solutions given there and it didn't help.

Comment: is your issue the same as any of these? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22.NET+Core+SDK+cannot+be+located%3A+A+valid+dotnet+installation+could+not+be+found%22

Comment: @starball I receive the same error message, yes.